# create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument ''

Tags: python, django, django-models, root

I'am trying create my custom User model for authentication, but I, can't see the error in my code, maybe you can see and help me.

Believe me I search in whole forum before posting, even [I read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705943/typeerror-create-user-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-name), but this is about hash password

when I try create an superuser in shell with command

```
c:\employee>python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I get the following error (complete traceback at bottom)

```
create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'NickName'
```

here is my seetings.py

```
#seetings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Sinergia.Employee'
```

and my models.py

```
#models.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models


# Importando la configuración
from django.conf import settings

# Importando clases para los administradores
# de usuario.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class EmployeeManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, nickname, password = None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('must have an email address.')

        usuario =   self.model\
                    (
                        Email = self.normalize_email(email),
                        NickName = nickname,
                    )
        usuario.set_password(password)
        usuario.save(using = self._db)
        return usuario

    def create_superuser(self, email, nickname, password):
        usuario =   self.create_user\
                    (
                        email = email,
                        nickname = nickname,
                        password = password,

                    )
        usuario.is_admin = True
        usuario.save(using = self._db)
        return usuario


class Employee(AbstractBaseUser):
    Email       = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, unique = True)
    NickName    = models.CharField(max_length = 40, unique = True)
    FBAccount   = models.CharField(max_length = 300)

    # Estados del Usuario.
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    object = EmployeeManager()

    # Identificador Único del Usuario.
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'

    # Campos obligatorios.
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['NickName']


    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.Email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.NickName

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin



class Article(models.Model):
    Author       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo when you assign the manager:

```
class Employee(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    objects = EmployeeManager()
```

objects, not `object`.

Comment: But that won't affect the model. `objects` always exists.

Comment: @YuvalAdam Yes, but OP is trying to override `objects.create_superuser()` so it adds a nickname argument, which doesn't appear in the default version.

Comment: I modify my class changing `object` by `objects` but the error continues

Answer (score 2):

What my problem solved is the addition of `**extra_fields` like this:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password,**extra_fields):
       """
       Creates and saves a superuser with the given email,  and password.
       """
       user = self.create_user(email,
           password=password,**extra_fields
       )
       user.is_admin = True
       user.save()

       return user
```

May it also solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You are using `CamelCase` for your field names, it is not a good practice, and it's causing the errors.

Hence, your function fails when you call (in `create_superuser()`):

```
self.create_user(email = email, nickname = nickname, password = password)
```

Either call:

```
self.create_user(Email = email, NickName = nickname, password = password)
```

Or alternatively make all your field names `lowercase`.

Comment: I changed my declaration on my field names and my function arguments to lowercase but I get same error

Comment: @ElioClímacoHerrera this change requires a database migration, did you run one?

Answer (score 0):

1- You should inherit from **PermissionMixin**

in the Employee

```
class Employee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     .....
```

Because of the **USERNAME_FIELD**
Exist on **PermissionMixin** class so you can override it.

2- **objects** not **object**